# How to place a question mark button in a NSAlert that opens an online web page?

Tags: macos, nsalert

EDIT: My question was not very clear now I edited it to make it clear that I need to open an online web page and not the help book.

I would like to include a question mark button in a NSAlert in a macOS project that points to an online web page with the help resource.

I saw [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsalert) that there are two possibilities:

> var showsHelp: Bool Specifies whether the alert has a help button.
>
> var helpAnchor: String? The alert’s HTML help anchor.

But I can't figure out how to implement it.

I use this code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let myAlert: NSAlert = NSAlert()

    myAlert.messageText = "Message"
    myAlert.informativeText = "Informative text."

    myAlert.showsSuppressionButton = true

    myAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Later")
    myAlert.addButton(withTitle: "Now")
    myAlert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")

    let choice = myAlert.runModal()

    switch choice {
    case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
        print ("OK")
    case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
        print ("Now")
    case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn:
        print ("Later")
    default: break

    }
    if myAlert.suppressionButton!.state == 1 {
        print ("Checked")
    } else {
        print ("Not checked")
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want the Help button to open your app's help book? Or do you want it to perform a more customized action?

Comment: Hi Ken, I would like to open an online page, not the help book. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your controller class conform to `NSAlertDelegate`.
Then, set `myAlert.delegate = self` and `myAlert.showsHelp = true`.
In your controller class, implement `func alertShowHelp(_ alert: NSAlert) -> Bool` to do whatever you like.

In general, to open URLs in the user's default browser, use `NSWorkspace` and its `open()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `helpAnchor` property to set the help anchor, which can redirect to a section in the documentation or a website.

> **var helpAnchor** 
>   The alert’s HTML help anchor.
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsalert/1534314-helpanchor

Example:

```
var alert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = "Testing"
alert.helpAnchor = "https://google.com"
alert.showsHelp = true
alert.runModal()
```

That won't work because the URL is not set as a HelpBook, to set that see this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/using_ah_functions/using_ah_functions.html

For opening external websites:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEAADH

Please note that the built-in question mark button only supports opening the built in Help window, not internet browsers. If you want to open in a web browser, you have to create a whole custom `NSAlert` and provide your own `accessoryView`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Dialog/Articles/CustomAlertDialogs.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it don't answer my question I think. Actually I would like to know how to open an online web page. I'm a beginner in this field and I can't find in the documents you linked how to do this.

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEAADH

"Opening an External Web Page in Help Viewer"